# How to send sign in info to frontend after successful Oauth2 authorization in devise_token_auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, devise, devise-token-auth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for Email and Google Oauth2 based authentication(used `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem for this). I've successfully managed to store sign in info of the user signing up/in through Google Oauth2 flow. The info includes:

```
{"auth_token"=>"token here", "client_id"=>"client id here", "uid"=>"uid here", "expiry"=>1620492005, "config"=>nil, "oauth_registration"=>true}
```

The flow for the above info was

1. Visit http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2. This redirects you to the Google auth screen
2. User selects account and grants permission.
3. Oauth success callback from my app is executed at http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback

The code which executes for the first step is

```
module DeviseTokenAuth
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController
    attr_reader :auth_params

    before_action :validate_auth_origin_url_param
    
    def omniauth_success
      get_resource_from_auth_hash
      set_token_on_resource
      create_auth_params

      if confirmable_enabled?
        # don't send confirmation email!!!
        @resource.skip_confirmation!
      end

      sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)

      @resource.save!

      yield @resource if block_given?

      render_data_or_redirect('deliverCredentials', @auth_params.as_json, @resource.as_json)
    end
  end
end
```

Problems I'm facing:

1. `sign_in` method call does not set `@current_user` despite that `@resource` and `@auth_params` have all the necessary info in them.
2. How can I inform my frontend app about the sign in info(token, client_id, uid)?

```
render_data_or_redirect('deliverCredentials', @auth_params.as_json, @resource.as_json)
```

this call does not redirect or render anything, instead it stays on the same page the URL it shows is http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback#

I basically have three questions now:

1. How can I use `devise_token_auth` to set the `current_user` based on the incoming auth headers?
   I have added the following line to my controller, but still it fails to set `@current_user`

```
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
```

maybe it is because I'm sending auth headers incorrectly? See my 3rd point below for this.

2. How am I supposed to send the sign in info to my frontend app?
   Do I modify the above method somehow to send sign in info to my frontend app?
3. What and where do I put the auth headers in order to make authenticated requests?

- When using `devise_token_auth` with email as auth provider I have to send 3 pieces to make an authenticated request i.e `access-token`, `client_id` and `uid`
- Now in case of providers like Google/Facebook etc, do I set all of these headers or not?

I have used postman to test both of the following but it failed with Unauthorized error

1. Sent `access-token`, `client_id` and `uid` in headers
2. Sent `Bearer my_token` in authorization headers.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? I'm stuck on the same question on how to send the info back to the front end

Comment: I used [j-toker](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker) to handle authentication on the front-end side. See the repo link, it also has a live demo and the code of demo is available as well.

Comment: Thanks @Masroor, J-toker made it WAY easier. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working, we had to override the `DeviseTokenAuth`'s `OmniAuthCallbacks` controller and update its `render_data_or_redirect` [method](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/7806104dc7c956dca2859e95077890b7a3f5fc87/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb#L216).

The default definition of `render_data_or_redirect` is

```rb
def render_data_or_redirect(message, data, user_data = {})
  if ['inAppBrowser', 'newWindow'].include?(omniauth_window_type)
    render_data(message, user_data.merge(data))
  elsif auth_origin_url

    redirect_to DeviseTokenAuth::Url.generate(auth_origin_url, data.merge(blank: true))
  else
    fallback_render data[:error] || 'An error occurred'
  end
end
```

The following `routes.rb` and `custom_omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` have the changes needed to be done to get it working with `j-toker` library.

In the routes file

```rb
# config/routes.rb

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
  omniauth_callbacks: "devise_token_auth/custom_omniauth_callbacks"
}
```

and the definition of `CustomOmniAuthCallbacksController` was

```rb
# app/controllers/devise_token_auth/custom_omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

module DeviseTokenAuth
  class CustomOmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController
    protected

    def render_data_or_redirect(message, data, user_data = {})
      if (['inAppBrowser', 'newWindow'].include?(omniauth_window_type) || auth_origin_url)

        redirect_to DeviseTokenAuth::Url.generate(auth_origin_url, data.merge(blank: true))
      else
        fallback_render data[:error] || 'An error occurred'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

now on the front-end side you need to configure `j-toker`

First, install j-toker package, [yarn package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/j-toker) or [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/j-toker)

```sh
yarn add j-toker
```

or

```sh
npm i j-toker
```

then in your javascript application, configure the `j-toker`

```js
import $ from "jquery";

$.auth.configure({
    apiUrl: "https://your-api-domain.com",
    emailSignInPath: "/auth/sign_in",
    signOutPath: "/auth/sign_out",
    emailRegistrationPath: "/auth",
    tokenValidationPath: "/auth/validate_token"

    authProviderPaths: {
      facebook: "/auth/facebook",
      google: "/auth/google_oauth2"
    }
  });
```